# Using Javascript/Php: Trying to display background image - logic wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So I want to display a background image (that is the thumbnail image in wordpress post) using css in `hero-wrapper` div if the screen size is min. 900px.

I have using php to check if there is a thumbnail image, then using javascript to check screen width and then adding background-image property to the dive. Not working, I think my logic is wrong??

HTML

```
    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <?php    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                if (jQuery(window).width() == 900) {
                 <?php echo '<section class="hero-wrapper" style="background-image: url(' . $thumb['0']. ') >'; ?>
                }
            </script>   
    <?php } ?>  
    <section class="hero-wrapper">

        <figure class="frontpage-hero">
            <div class="banner-box">
                <h2>GET YOUR FREE CASE ASSESSMENT?</h2>
                <h6>Enter your details below for a consultation</h6>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
                </form>     
            </div>           
        </figure>

    </section>
```

css

```
.hero-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 669px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@media screen (min-width: 900px) {
    .hero-wrapper {
        min-height: 669px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not checked the syntax but your jQuery window width is only checking if the value returned is equal to 900, not  900 or greater

Comment: Perhaps your div has no width and height. Then you will not see the background image.

Comment: @Kokodoko i've added the css, have a min-height

Comment: @netpraxis new to javascript and php, what would be an alternative way of checking for screen width and adding php image?

Comment: as @netpraxis says: if (jQuery(window).width() >= 900) {

Comment: Don't you need a `min-width` too? I suggest first testing the CSS with a default image. If that works, add the php check and if that works, add the screen-width check.

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing a `<section>` tag inside a `<script>` tag.
You should change this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            if (jQuery(window).width() == 900) {
             <?php echo '<section class="hero-wrapper" style="background-image: url(' . $thumb['0']. ') >'; ?>
            }
        </script>
```

To something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            if (jQuery(window).width() >= 900) {
             $('.hero-wrapper').css('background-image', 'url(' + <?php echo $thumb['0']; ?> + ')');
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Your approach will not work in a case if window size will change. It will also requre jQuery to be available by the time of browser's parser will reach this part of the page. And your code will not actually create element.

Comment: @Flying From the question I got the impression OP was trying to update the existing div which has the "hero-wrapper" class. It's not 100% clear but that seems to be the intent. So in that respect this answer would be fine.

Comment: Taking in mind that it is wordpress page template (take a look at `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`) - he obviously tries to generate page and messed up server and client code.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong twice:

1. your `jQuery(window).width() == 900` condition will run only once and will not reflect window size changes
2. you're trying to use php (server side language) to output html (client side markup) inside javascript (client side code) code block. You will end up with syntax error.

Correct approach is to just output your html element and use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) to control its appearance. Something like:

```
.hero-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .hero-wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Please also notice that image displayed as background will not enforce element to have any height and hence your element will show up with 0px height (invisible in other words). You will need to specify element's dimensions somehow (and remember that images may have different aspect ratios).

After all it may be easier for you to not use background image but insert normal image instead and control its dimensions using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding anything to the existing "hero-wrapper" div with your code, you're just echoing some HTML within a Javascript block, which won't achieve anything. You've almost certainly got syntax errors in your console. The final rendered page will look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (jQuery(window).width() == 900) {
        <section class="hero-wrapper" style="background-image: url('thumbnail.png') >
    }
</script>   
<section class="hero-wrapper">
    <figure class="frontpage-hero">
```

...etc

This will get you a JS console error along the lines of:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Even if that part worked, the HTML is also invalid because you never close the style attribute with a ", and this code will only ever execute when the window width is *exactly* 900px, which I don't think you intended.

What you need to be doing is altering the existing div to add the style, and also allow it when the width is greater than or equal to 900px. This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 900) {
      $(".hero-wrapper").css("background-image", "url('<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>')");
    }
});
</script>
```

I also wrapped the code in `document.ready` so that it won't run until the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the javascript and do this in your CSS media queries with display: none; to hide the element for screens under 900px i.e

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
echo '<section class="hero-wrapper" style="background-image: url(' . $thumb['0']. ') >'; 
} ?>
```

And in your CSS

```
@media screen (min-width: 900px) {
    .hero-wrapper {
        min-height: 669px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen (max-width: 900px) {
    .hero-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
}
```